# How can I add multiple charts in row

Tags: birt, birt-deapi

My requirement is to draw 3 charts in a row and break the row after that for next sequence of charts

Comment: This question does not show any attempt to solve the problem before asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this using BIRT Designer:

- Add a grid and put a chart into each cell
- Add a table, group the contents, put a chart in the group footer, hide the details rows
- Add a crosstab, change the aggregated totals to charts and hide whatever content you want hidden
- Use dynamic text, HTML, and the JavaScript API to display the charts in divs

Organize your grouping or crosstab dimensions to be in sets of 3.